# Dijkstra Algorithm Application

Tags: dijkstra

Suppose we have a network and in some cases there is the same weight between two servers
how the algorithm is gonna work on that case ? ...for example:

C---> F  weight is 2
C--->B weight is 2

Here's the problem...find the shortest way out from A to K.While applying the standard algorithm I get stuck, facing two egdes with the same weight, for instance from C---> F  weight is 2 and C--->B weight is 2.

[image]

Comment: Its very complicated algorithm you have show your exact need and in which language you want to implement it. Then after anybody can help you.

Comment: I'd say, if there's a tie, just pick one randomly. Eventually, all relevant possibilities will be explored by Dijkstra's algorithm. The result will be _an_ optimal solution. In network routing, that's good enough; you don't have to know _how many_ optimal solutions there are. Unless you are facing specific requirements we should know about?